# Ignore null in SetProperty of EF Core 7

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I'm trying to use `ExecuteUpdateAsync` in EF Core 7. The problem I have is that the client might not send all properties, so if I use `ExecuteUpdateAsync` the property in the database will be null. But I want it to behave like this.

If the dto property is null, then don't do anything.

This is part of my code:

```
await _dbContext.Set<UserEntity>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == dto.Id)
                .ExecuteUpdateAsync(x => x.SetProperty(y => y.Bio, dto.Bio));
```

I want to update Bio of the user. but I don't want it to update it as `NULL` if `dto.Bio` is null.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why not `if (dto.Bio is not null) {do stuff} else {do nothing}`

Comment: well sorry, for simplicity I just add one of the properties in the question, but there are about 20 properties in dto and entity

Comment: Why the do you use `ExecuteUpdate`? ChangeTracker do that automatically.

Comment: Not too elegant, but you could use `x.SetProperty(y => y.Bio, dto.Bio ?? y.Bio)` etc.

Comment: @GertArnold already tried. efcore can't handle this and throws error.

Comment: Which error? My code runs fine.